# Windows XP Professional SP3 system performance improvement with additional ram

Tags: windows-xp, memory, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will adding extra RAM in my computer speed it up?](https://superuser.com/questions/412664/will-adding-extra-ram-in-my-computer-speed-it-up)

I have a system with Windows XP professional 64 bit SP3 installed. It's main hardware is as follows

```
Motherboard: P5KPL-VM
CPU : Intel Pentium Dual CPU e2140 @ 1.6 Ghz
Memory : 1GB DDR2 PC2 xxxx (not sure which one of 5200,6400 or 8500)
No GPU
```

The performance isn't stellar to say the least with recent software. It seems to be sluggish in browsing and regular office related task. It's usable but not snappy.

I am thinking of upgrading its RAM as its a relatively unused and system so it has much life left in it. The idea is to use for network storage and if possible to run additional services on it.

My question, is will upgrading ram to 4GB (2GB per slot) help? 
I am not sure where the performance issue is at this time or how to find the bottleneck.

EDIT: If you can help please reply, ask for more info is allright. Please don't show existing topics. I have read them and they either don't apply or don't help me.

Xperf: It's a good tool, but not going to istall the SDK etc which will only take too much time and more system resources. Something simpler like hdtune would help, a standlone app.

Additional info about applications since someone asked.:

```
Chrome Browser, youtube, social networking etc.
Office 2003
Printing, Scanning and browsing Media
```

I have included as much information as needed. No reason to downvote, but I know people do that for their own skewed reasons.
I am trying ti understand if the RAM is too low for general purpose in contemporary context and as compared to rest of the system specs.

Comment: Which browser? Which programs for *office related tasks*?

Comment: @Journeyman I have already read it before posting. I hope you will be less condescending. I am more concerned that just ram is enough or not and how do I find it out. You just had me repeat my Q

Comment: I covered that there. It could be as simple as checking how much ram you're using - if you have loads spare, its probably not the ram. If you have not enough, it could be your ram OR your hard disk. Or the processor... All the suggestions i've given there are true here as well.

Comment: IF you can get 4GB RAM almost for free and IF you can overclock the processor to lets say 2.4GHz you could buy a 120GB SSD and get another year out of it. Personally, I would buy a new system (with a SSD).

Comment: @Journeyman, thanks. Windows takes 50% of ram as usual seems 512 MB may not be enough for modern browsers.

Comment: @Oggy the RAM is inexpensive, 4GB will cost less than 90$. The Disk is a fairly new SATAII. Another year for 100 bucks seems enough. SSD seems overkill for storage and browsing and SSD are expensive by itself. But good ideas.

Comment: This is a not duplicate , man these admins are annoying. I have read those posts, they dont answer my question neither is the question same. >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes increasing your RAM memory will help. The latest software, assuming that you are trying to use that, requires reasonable amount of memory. Your primary problem is that your processor is old.

Comment: so you are saying its better to get new system?

Comment: Yeah.. but it largely depends on what you are trying to achieve and how much **budget** you have. Say if you just want to surf the web, perhaps you will be fine if you just increase the ram.

Comment: thanks. I will go with your suggestion and get atleast 2GB of ram if not 4. That should buy me time and I can always install linux to get more power if RAM is all that's slowing things down.